# need help with triangular inequality

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I need to show that $||x|-|y||\le|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$.
I proved the right inequality, $|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$, and now I need to prove the left inequality, $||x|-|y||\le|x+y|$.

I though that I could do it by using the definition of the absolute value, which means that I need to prove that
$-|x+y|\le|x|-|y|\le|x+y|$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.
How can I prove the last inequality?

Comment: $|(x+y)+(-y)| \le |x+y|+|(-y)|$.

Comment: Hint: $|x|=|x+y+(-y)|$.

Comment: If you check out my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487575/how-can-i-derive-this-expression-related-to-the-triangle-inequality), I think you may very well get what you seek!

Comment: ok i think i proved the right one: $|x|=|x+y-y|=|x+y+(-y)|\le|x+y|+|-y|=|x+y|+|y|$ that proves that $|x|\le|x+y|+|y|$ how about the left one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\bullet\;\;|x|=|x+y+(-y)|\le|x+y|+|y|\implies \begin{cases}|x|-|y|\le|x+y|\\{}\\|y|-|x|\ge -|x+y|\;\end{cases}\;\implies\ldots$$

And remember that for $\,x,a\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;a\ge 0$ :

$$|x|\le a\iff -a\le x\le a$$

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i got it.

i need to show that $||x|−|y||≤|x+y|$ which means that $-|x+y|\le|x|-|y|\le|x+y|$.
which means that i need to show that $|y|-|x+y|\le|x|\le|x+y|+|y|$

in general $|x|=|x+y-y|=|x+y+(-y)|$ and $|y|=|x+y-x|=|x+y+(-x)|$

now we know that $|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$ so $|x+y+(-y)|\le|x+y|+|-y|=|x+y|+|y|$ and $|x+y+(-x)|\le|x+y|+|y|$

so we have $|x|\le|x+y|+|y|$ (which proves the right side) and $|y|\le|x+y|+|x|$ which means that $|y|-|x+y|\le|x|$ (which proves the left side)
so we get $|y|-|x+y|\le|x|\le|x+y|+|y|$ which proves that $||x|−|y||≤|x+y|$

is everything ok here?

Comment: @ Yossi:  A cursory reading yields no obvious errors, looks OK to me.  The inequality is usually written in the (equivalent) form $\vert \vert x \vert  - \vert y \vert \vert \le \vert x - y \vert$.  But no matter.