# Triangle Inequality with complex numbers: Prove that ||x|−|y||≤|x|-|y|.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Prove that $ ||x| - |y|| \le |x| - |y| $ for all $ x,y \in \mathbb{C} $.

I fully understand the other inequality:
$|x+y| \le |x|+|y| $ for all $ x,y \in \mathbb{C} $.

But I have no clue how to start this one.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof) and the questions linked there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice $$|x| = |x + y - y| \leq |x - y| + |y| \implies |x| - |y| \leq |x-y| $$

By the same reasoning, you can do the same with $y$ instead of $x$, and obtain the desired result, the reversed triangle inequality.

Comment: thanks! That was fast and really helpful. God bless!

Answer (score 5):

First off, the assertion $\vert \vert x \vert - \vert y \vert \vert \le \vert x \vert - \vert y \vert$ is false: to see this, just choose $\vert y \vert > \vert x \vert$.  I think what you want is $ \vert  \vert x \vert - \vert y \vert  \vert \le \vert x - y \vert$, as was stated and correctly demonstrated by Citizen in his/her answer.

Having said these things, and to avoid re-writing what is essentially the same answer over and over, you might check out my answer to this question:

[How can I derive this expression related to the triangle inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487575/how-can-i-derive-this-expression-related-to-the-triangle-inequality)

Hope this helps!  Cheers!