# Absolute value properties: inequality $|x|-|y| \le |x-y|$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I'm attempting to prove that $|x|-|y| \le |x-y|$.

I've come up with the following proof.

The proof relies on these results obtained from previous exercises:

1. $-|x| \le x \le |x|$
2. ${|x-y|=|y-x|}$

**Case 1.** $x \le 0$, $y \le 0$. Here, we have $|x|-|y| = -x -(-y) = y-x$. Since $y-x \le |y-x| = |x-y|$, it follows that $|x|-|y| \le |x-y|$.

**Case 2.**  $x \ge 0$, $y \le 0$. In this case, we have $|x|-|y| = x-(-y) = x+y$. Since, here, $y\le x$, it is the case that $x-y \ge 0$; thus, $|x-y| = x-y$. Observe that $y\le -y$. Adding $x$ to both sides of the inequality gives us $x+y \le x-y$. Hence,  we have $|x|-|y| \le |x-y|$ as desired.

**Case 3.** $x\le0, y\ge 0$. Here, $|x|-|y| = -x-y$. Since, in this case, $x\le y$, we have $x-y \le 0$; thus, $|x-y| = -(x-y) = y-x$. Here, we have $-y \le y$. Adding $-x$ to both sides gives us $-x-y \le y-x$. Thus, $|x|-|y| \le |x-y|$.

**Case 4.** $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$. In this case, $|x|-|y| = x-y$. Since $x-y \le |x-y|$, it follows that $|x|-|y| \le |x-y|$ as desired.

I suspect there is a more straightforward or brief proof for this out there. Can someone point me in that direction?

Comment: Can you use the standard triangle inequality $|a+b|\leq |a| + |b|$?

Comment: Forgot about the most basic case somehow..

Comment: See also:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488194/triangle-inequality-with-complex-numbers-prove-that-x%E2%88%92y%E2%89%A4x-y
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989349/proving-the-reverse-triangle-inequality-of-the-complex-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:
$$|x| - |y| = |x-y+y|-|y| \leq |x-y| + |y| - |y| = |x-y|$$
Using only one triangle inequality and working for any norm.

Answer (score 5):

If we know the triangle inequality: $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$ then 
$$|x|=|x-y+y|\leq |x-y|+|y|\iff|x|-|y|\leq|x-y|$$

Comment: Simplicity is beautiful in Maths, Sami. +)

Comment: Simple beauty, indeed!