# Prove for some $z_0 \in C$ the function $f(z)=|z-z_0|$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification, continuity

Let $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ and $f(z)=|z-z_0|$. Show that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$. I expect to see a proof using the triangle inequality.

---

Note a function $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$ if for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, then
\begin{equation}
\lim_{z \to \alpha} f(z) = f(\alpha)
\end{equation}
i.e.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{z \to \alpha} |z-z_0| = |\alpha-z_0|
\end{equation}

---

**Edit**: I posted my attempted solution as an answer below. Thanks Winther and Mario Carneiro for their help!

Comment: How about using $||x|-|y||\le||x||+|\!-\!|y||=|x|+|y|$? You are right that the step you make at the end is not valid, although you can proceed (a little less elegantly) by case analysis if you also show that $f(\alpha)-f(z)<\epsilon$, since $f$ is real.

Comment: Great suggestion, thank you! I revised the proof and posted it as a potential answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In what follows, we will use the [Reverse Triangle Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487575/how-can-i-derive-this-expression-related-to-the-triangle-inequality): for complex numbers $x$ and $y$,
\begin{equation}
||x|-|y|| \le |x-y|
\end{equation}
Let $\epsilon>0$, and choose $\delta=\epsilon$. Then $|z-\alpha|<\delta$ implies $|z-\alpha|<\epsilon$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
|z-z_0+z_0-\alpha|=|z-\alpha|<\epsilon
\end{equation}
which, applying the Reverse Triangle Inequality, implies
\begin{align*}
||z-z_0|-|\alpha-z_0||
&\le |\left(z-z_0\right)-\left(\alpha-z_0\right)| \\
&= |z-z_0+z_0-\alpha| \\
&=|z-\alpha|<\epsilon
\end{align*}
which shows
\begin{equation}
|f(z)-f(\alpha)|<\epsilon
\end{equation}
proving $\lim_{z \to \alpha} f(z) = f(\alpha)$.

Comment: Why is $|z-z_0| + |z_0-\alpha| \leq |z-\alpha|$? If you take $z_0=0$ then it says $|z| + |\alpha| \leq |z-\alpha|$ which is not correct, just take $z=\alpha$ to see this.

Comment: You're right. I have the triangle inequality reversed in that statement. Any way I can fix this?

Comment: Can you show $||x|-|y||\le|x-y|$? I take my earlier statement back, I don't think there is an easier way to do this than just by case analysis on the real $|\cdot|$ function, i.e. show $|x|-|y|\le|x-y|$ and $|y|-|x|\le|x-y|$.

Comment: Yes, you need the reversed triange inequality: $||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|$. See for example [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487575/how-can-i-derive-this-expression-related-to-the-triangle-inequality) for proofs of several expressions related to the triangle inequality.

Comment: Edited my answer. Does it work now? Thanks all!